# I am facing issue with ParquetFileWriting n hdfs in flink where parquet file size is around 382 KB . I want the parquet file in MB

Tags: apache-flink, parquet

```java
AvroParquetWriter.<GenericRecord>builder(filePath)
 .withSchema(schema)
 .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
 .withConf(Configuration)
 .withDataModel(GenericData.get())
 .withWriteMode(Mode.OVERWRITE)
 .withRowGroupSize(8*1024*10124)
 .withPageSize(64*1024*1024)
 .build()
```

For `Path` I am using a logic path = "hdfsLocation"+String.format(tid%num of rows per file),counter/number of rows per file)+_parquet. With these I am able to achieve file size of 382 KB, but I need file size around 100 MB. Please share some solution.

Comment: What version of Flink are you using? And please include the code you're using to create the Flink sink.

Comment: I am using 1.17.0 version

Comment: this is the main code for writing file other than i  just using datumWriter and record to add individual values.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.